# Choosing an equlation from api response Python

Tags: python, api, request

Im trying to work with api responses;

Here is the example response that comes from api;

```
{u'blog': {u'followed': False, u'is_adult': False, u'can_subscribe': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'ask': True, u'likes': 920, u'is_blocked_from_primary': False, u'can_submit': True, u'ask_anon': True, u'subscribed': False, u'share_likes': True, u'updated': 1493576375, u'description': u'<p>"Che hai dei bellissimi occhi quando mi cerchi."</p><p>18 </p><p>Beginner Wiccan and Witch </p><p>\U0001f312\U0001f315\U0001f318</p>', u'total_posts': 13992, u'submission_page_title': u'Submit', u'submission_terms': {u'title': u'Submit', u'tags': [], u'guidelines': u'', u'accepted_types': [u'text', u'photo', u'quote', u'link', u'video']}, u'name': u'darknessinmyheartt', u'url': u'http://darknessinmyheartt.tumblr.com/', u'ask_page_title': u'lets ask something!/ haydi sor!', u'title': u'"Laurel"', u'posts': 13992, u'reply_conditions': u'3', u'can_send_fan_mail': False}}
```

how can ı get only the value of u'updated' from that response

```
u'updated': 1493576375
```

I have to define that value to "x"

Comment: You may want to post more code, as it is, it's difficult to understand your question. It seems to be a dictionary, if so, `print name_of_dic['updated']`

Comment: Its tumblr api and its the response of

client.blog_info('darknessinmyheartt')

I am trying to get the time when blog is updated, so the first line i wrote is the response api sends "u'updated': 1493576375" means the time in Epoch. I need to find the time passed from the last update so i need to eject that time from current time.  i need this value as int. but i cant define it

Comment: `code`
>>> client.blog_info('darknessinmyheartt')
{u'blog': {u'followed': False, u'is_adult': False, u'can_subscribe': False, u'is_nsfw': False, u'ask': True, u'likes': 920, u'is_blocked_from_primary': False, u'can_submit': True, u'ask_anon': True, u'subscribed': False, u'share_likes': True, u'updated': 1493578459...
>>> x = client.blog_info('darknessinmyheartt')
>>> updatetime = u'updated'(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
`code`

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: I already checked 

`
print x['updated']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'updated' `

Comment: I never mentioned `print x['updated']`, but `x['blog']['updated']` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `tumblr` api response is a python `dict`, based on that, try:

```
x = client.blog_info('darknessinmyheartt')
print x['blog']['updated']
```

Answer (score 1):

You got `json` response, in Python you can get value from `json` data, via key.

For your example, you need to do next things:

```
your_data['blog']['updated']
```

via `your_data['blog']`  You will get object with key, values

```
{'followed': False, u'is_adult': False, u'can_subscribe': False, ....}
```

and via `your_data['blog']['updated']` you will get value `1493576375`

Comment: also its worked too it is the same code that i wrote